# Is it good practice or necessary to use a Service to use a Media Player in the backgound

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hello StackOverflow's users,
I'm developing a Music Player App for android. In my main activity when the user clicks on a song I start a new intent that displays PlayerActivity. In there, I initialize a MediaPlayer and all the other UI elements. When the user clicks the back button, I bring them back to the main activity and the song continues to play in the background. The same thing happens if they exit the application. Now I was wondering if it's fine to do something like this or if I should instead start a new Service for the MediaPlayer from the PlayerActivity class instead of doing it in there.

PlayerActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarDividerColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    playBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    artImage = findViewById(R.id.art);
    remainingTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.current_song_duration);
    totalTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.total_duration);
    manager = MainActivity.getManager();

    Song song = manager.getCurrentSong();

    boolean wasCall = extras != null && extras.containsKey("call");
    if (!wasCall && manager.hasStarted()) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = manager.getMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }


    if (!wasCall) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(song.getPath()));
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
    } else {
        mp = manager.getMediaPlayer();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
    }

    totalTime = mp.getDuration();
    artImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(song.getIcon(), 250, 250, true));

    totalTimeLabel.setText(createTimeLabel(totalTime));

    songName = findViewById(R.id.songName);
    songName.setText(song.getName());

    songAuthor = findViewById(R.id.songAuthor);
    songAuthor.setText(song.getArtist());

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.player_top_bar);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    assert toolbar.getNavigationIcon() != null;
    toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>MySound</font>"));

    positionBar =  findViewById(R.id.seek_song_progressbar);
    positionBar.setMax(totalTime);
    positionBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (fromUser) {
                        mp.seekTo(progress);

                        positionBar.setProgress(progress);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            }
    );

    LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.player_control);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    new Thread(() -> {
        while (mp != null) {
            try {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    this.action = SongEndAction.REPEAT;

    mp.start();
    manager.setMediaPlayer(mp);
}
```

Comment: Playing a music is a background task so you better use a background service for it (Activity should handle UI events not background music playing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Music Service that I implemented in my book. 
https://github.com/Wickapps/Practical-Android-MusicService
This implementation includes play, stop, and seek forward, but you could add other functions.
Service is the best architecture for future scalability.
There is a MainActivity.java which starts the service.
MusicService.java is the service implementation.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you advise me to parse an instance of my PlayerActivity to the service and change drawables from the service or to keep only the music player function in there and update the drawables from PlayerActivity?

Comment: It sounds like it would be best for you to manage your playlist and your drawables (I assume you mean image related to what is playing) from the activity because it can update the UI.

Comment: For some reason, onCreate is never called.

Comment: It works if I put your code in the main class, but if I put it In the PlayerAtcivity class it won't

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that, you should be able to bind the service to any activity. Better double check your AndroidManifest and make sure all the Activity and Service are defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to keep playing audio while it's in background ( like spotify ), then yes, it is a must to use a foreground service.

Unfortunately it's more complex than your current implementation.

This is a nice starting point : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app